# How to use LSD Slam with a USB Webcam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, webcam, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you use [LSD Slam](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam) with a generic USB webcam accessible to /dev/video1?

The README's quickstart guide works flawlessly for me with Indigo. However, their instructions for using live_slam with a video source is:

```
rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam /image:=<yourstreamtopic> /camera_info:=<yourcamera_infotopic>
```

but they don't explain what the values for  and <yourcamera_infotopic> should be. How do I fill these in appropriately? I'm assuming one involves referencing the camera device, but there's no further documentation.

Also, how would I launch the lsd_slam_* nodes with roslaunch? I tried creating mypackage/launch/webcam_lsd_slam.launch

```
<launch>
    <node name="webcam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
        <param name="image_width" value="640" />
        <param name="image_height" value="480" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
        <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
    </node>
    <node name="mapper" pkg="lsd_slam_core" type="live_slam" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw" />
    </node>
    <node name="viewer" pkg="lsd_slam_viewer" type="viewer" respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [usb_cam/usb_cam_node]: usb_cam
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/rosbuild_ws/mypackage
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [lsd_slam_core/live_slam]: lsd_slam_core
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/rosbuild_ws/mypackage
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [lsd_slam_viewer/viewer]: lsd_slam_viewer
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/rosbuild_ws/mypackage
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Presumably because the build didn't create true ROS packages for lsd_slam_core or lsd_slam_viewer. Predictably, `rospack find lsd_slam_core` finds nothing. How do I fix that?

Per the build instructions, the lsd_slam_core and lsd_slam_viewer folders were located in /home/user/rosbuild_ws/mypackage/lsd_slam, so I tried relocating them to /home/user/rosbuild_ws/mypackage, but that did nothing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208413/how-to-use-lsd-slam-with-a-usb-webcam/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-05-03**:
good starting point: http://answers.ros.org/question/9089/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera/

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-08-09**:
Hi Cerin, I want to do the same things with you.I add a launch file which is the same with you.But when I ran it, there have some error. And I put it in the answers 4, plz give me some advise.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the lsd_slam project in the wrong location. I created a workspace like:

```
~/workspace
    src
        lsd_slam_test
            lsd_slam
```

when it should have been like:

```
~/workspace
    src
        lsd_slam
        lsd_slam_test
```

After that, the next problem I ran into was that lsd_slam can't handle color video, so I had to convert it to mono using an image_proc node:

```
<!-- This will read a camera and show a streaming feed in a display window. -->
<launch>
    <!-- Activate the color webcam. -->
    <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
        <param name="image_width" value="640" />
        <param name="image_height" value="480" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
        <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
    </node>
    <!-- Convert the color webcam's output to mono. -->
    <node name="to_mono_node1" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="usb_cam" />
    <!-- Display the mono stream. -->
    <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_mono" />
        <param name="autosize" value="true" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

After that, lsd_slam ran correctly. Unfortunately, the performance and accuracy of the resulting depth map was unusably poor.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-07-02**:
Hello Cerin, I want to run lsd_slam using my webcam. I am newbie ROS and don't understand how you do.  I use ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte. my launch file is under fuerte_workspace.`roslaunch lsd_slam_core test.launch cannot locate [test.launch] in package [lsd_slam_core]`